# jquery image click event for specific images

Tags: jquery, html

I have images that are dynamically added to a page, and on that page I have a jquery function which shows when an image is clicked. It all works fine, but I have static images on the page that I don't want to be clickable for the function.

This is the jquery that runs whenever an image is selected. I can't use the`id` element of the images because they are different all the time.

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('img').click(function () {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How can I make it so only the images I want run with function when clicked?

Comment: why not give the images a class? then just select those ones like so: $('img.selectable').click(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add a class to your images which you want to be clickable.
For example:

```
<img class="clickableimage">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clickableimage').click(function () {
        //This will only  work for images having class ="clickableimage"
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class selector.

```
$('img.clickable').click(function () {
    //do something
};
```

https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/